# How to push an object to a Form Control Array

Tags: angular

I have a formGroup , one of the formControls is an array.

```
this.newPurchase = fb.group({
  supplierName: ["", Validators.required],
  supplierNumber: ["", Validators.required],
  supplierEmail: ['', Validators.required],
  stockitems: [[], Validators.required],
});
```

As you can see , stockitems is declared as an array and I would like to push an object to it.

This is what I tried:

```
exampleObject = {
name:'foo',
lastName:'fooAgain'
}

this.newPurchase.controls.stockitems.push(this.exampleObject)
```

The object did not get pushed into the array ,
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

```
this.newPurchase = fb.group({
  supplierName: ["", Validators.required],
  supplierNumber: ["", Validators.required],
  supplierEmail: ['', Validators.required],
  stockitems: this.fb.array([], Validators.required),
});
```

in your component, put this function:

```
get stockItemFormControls(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.newPurchase.get('stockitems');
  }
```

Then where needed:

```
this.stockItemFormControls.push(this.fb.group({name: 'foo', lastName:'fooAgain'}));
```

or

```
this.stockItemFormControls.push(this.fb.group(this.exampleObject));
```